# create a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

Would like to know how to create a calculated  column which is  equal to other column. ie, i am having a column  called BU in C-TYPE HUB and its propagated in my subscriber site collection say http://srvr1/sites/demo. i would like to create a new site column in Demo say BU_Calc that must be equal to the value of BU.i would like to use the BU_Calc for further processing

Answer (score 0):

create a calculated column with the following formula:

```
=[fieldname]
```

Comment: thanks @BOG Lab. i am trying to make this field  available in the subscriber site collec.i have created this calcu.column in the ct hub.Will this propogate the column in the other sites.